# Profile summary editor cannot add or edit fields in a reserved custom field-set

Tags: contact-summary-editor

I would like to rearrange the order and remove some fields we don't use in the contact summary Editor. I tried but it's giving me an error code saying you cannot add or edit fields in a reserved custom field-set.

Comment: Can you say more about your end goals? The definition of "reserved custom field set" is that the fields aren't editable.

Comment: Just need to drag the needed fields on the left form. i did not realized that at first.